# How to change new File method in Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How do I replace the new File method with a secure one? Is it possible to create a python script and connect it?

Part of the code where I have a problem:

```
def template Name = new File(file: "${template}").normalize.name.replace(".html", "").replace(".yaml", "")
```

But when I run my pipeline, I get the error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find constructor: new java.io .File java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

This method is prohibited and is [blacklisted](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist). How do I replace it and with what?

Comment: I think you want to use https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: Actually error saying that you are using File object constructor incorrectly. It should be without `file:` - like this `new File( "..." )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading the contents of the file, you can replace that "new File" with "readFile".
See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

> **readFile:** Read file from workspace
> Reads a file from a relative path (with root in current directory, usually > workspace) and returns its content as a plain string.
> **file :** String
> Relative (/-separated) path to file within a workspace to read.
> **encoding :** String (optional)
> The encoding to use when reading the file. If left blank, the platform default encoding will be used. Binary files can be read into a Base64-encoded string by specifying "Base64" as the encoding.